# Why isn't every space between words a feasible breakpoint?

Tags: line-breaking, tex-core, logging

p98 of the TeXbook gives a paragraph trace beginning:

```
[]\tenrm Mr. Drofnats---or ‘‘R. J.,’’ as he pre-
@\discretionary via @@0 b=0 p=50 d=2600
@@1: line 1.2- t=2600 -> @@0
ferred to be called---was hap-pi-est when
```

and adds

> Lines that begin with ‘@@’ represent feasible breakpoints, i.e., breakpoints that can be reached
> without any badness exceeding the tolerance. Feasible breakpoints are numbered consecutively,
> starting with @@1; the beginning of the paragraph is considered to be feasible too, and it is
> number @@0.

Why is the point labelled @@1 the first one? Can you not reach, say, the point between "as" and "he" without any badness exceeding the tolerance?

Comment: You could always use \sloppy.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Note that `\sloppy` sets `\tolerance` to `9999`: it won't make very bad (badness 10000) spaces into feasible breakpoints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try and compute the badness. The text

```
Mr.~Drofnats---or ``R. J.,'' as
```

has a width of 125.88911pt, to which we add 20pt because of `\parindent`.

The `\hsize` is 469.75499pt, so we need to stretch the glue to fill 343.86588pt and we have four globs of glue available, with stretchability 1.66666pt each, but the last one comes after a comma, so the space factor yields 2.08331pt. The total amount of stretchability is therefore 7.08329pt and the stretch ratio is 48.546

The badness is then computed using roughly 100 times the cube of the stretch ratio, that is, 11440952; this is too high and TeX uses 10000, as stated in the rules (p. 97, first doubly dangerous paragraph; the real rules are slightly different, but the idea is there).

If you try

```
\tracingparagraphs=1
\tracingonline=1
\tolerance=10000
\pretolerance=-1
\hyphenpenalty=10000
%\exhyphenpenalty=10000

Mr.~Drofnats---or ``R. J.,'' as
he preferred to be called---% error has been fixed!
was happiest when he was at work
typesetting beautiful documents.

\bye
```

you will see

```
[]\tenrm Mr. Drofnats---
@\discretionary via @@0 b=10000 p=50 d=100012500
@@1: line 1.0- t=100012500 -> @@0
or
@ via @@0 b=10000 p=0 d=100010000
@ via @@1 b=10000 p=0 d=100000000
@@2: line 1.0 t=100010000 -> @@0
``R.
@ via @@0 b=10000 p=0 d=100010000
@ via @@1 b=10000 p=0 d=100000000
@ via @@2 b=10000 p=0 d=100000000
@@3: line 1.0 t=100010000 -> @@0
J.,''
@ via @@0 b=10000 p=0 d=100010000
@ via @@1 b=10000 p=0 d=100000000
@ via @@2 b=10000 p=0 d=100000000
@ via @@3 b=10000 p=0 d=100000000
@@4: line 1.0 t=100010000 -> @@0
as
@ via @@0 b=10000 p=0 d=100010000
@ via @@1 b=10000 p=0 d=100000000
@ via @@2 b=10000 p=0 d=100000000
@ via @@3 b=10000 p=0 d=100000000
@ via @@4 b=10000 p=0 d=100000000
@@5: line 1.0 t=100010000 -> @@0
he
@ via @@0 b=10000 p=0 d=100010000
@ via @@1 b=10000 p=0 d=100000000
@ via @@2 b=10000 p=0 d=100000000
@ via @@3 b=10000 p=0 d=100000000
@ via @@4 b=10000 p=0 d=100000000
@ via @@5 b=10000 p=0 d=100000000
@@6: line 1.0 t=100010000 -> @@0
pre-ferred
```

(the remaining part is omitted). Here, every space is indeed a feasible break point, because the tolerance is never exceeded, as it's always normalized to 10000 if it would be above this bound.

In paragraph tracing, possible break points are not considered if the line would be stretched to exceed the tolerance; they would in case of shrinking, to allow paragraph breaking with overfull boxes in case no other sequence of break points can be achieved. The idea here is that overfull boxes are well visible (maybe with the help of `\overfullrule`), while underfull boxes are less easy to spot.

Why `\pretolerance=-1`? Because otherwise TeX would make a first pass without hyphenation. You might try with `\hyphenpenalty=10000` omitted, so also hyphenation points would be considered. However, you'd obtain essentially the same tracing by stating `\pretolerance=10000`.

Answer (score 8):

No, not every break can be reached without badness exceeding the tolerance: they would require too much stretching. You can try it out yourself: just insert a `\break` to force the break.

```
\tracingparagraphs=1
\tracingonline=1
\tracingoutput=1
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen

Mr.~Drofnats---or ``R. J.,'' as\break
he preferred to be called---%
was happiest when he was at work
typesetting beautiful documents.

\bye
```

The output will have:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 7--11
[]\tenrm Mr. Drofnats---or ``R. J.,'' as
```

and you can visually look at the output:

[image: output]

to see why the first line would have too much badness.